# Get Latest Event from mysql

Tags: mysql

I have `events` table. I want latest event which event type='appointment' and group on `type` and `instruction_id`. Problem is event_date come first '2013-12-02' instead of '2013-12-05'. More information required give comment I explain in detail.

My Expected output :

```
ID  INSTRUCTION_ID  TYPE    COMMENT     EVENT_DATE
3   2   appointment     at home     December, 05 2013 00:00:00+0000
10  1   appointment     at home     November, 22 2013 00:00:00+0000
5   3   appointment     office  September, 17 2013 00:00:00+0000
```

For more information check [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/25795a/41):

Comment: You are misusing `GROUP BY`. It makes no sense unless you have aggregate functions like `MAX()` or COUNT()` in your `SELECT` clause. Also please take the time to explain your required result set in more detail.

Comment: In addition for the first row as shown `3   2   appointment     at home     December, 05 2013 00:00:00+0000` `December, 05 2013 00:00:00+0000` has the id of the column as 11 if its the case of getting the max date not sure how it could be 3.. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/25795a/101

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below query:

```
select * 
from 
(SELECT * 
FROM EVENTS 
WHERE EVENTS.type='appointment'
ORDER BY EVENTS.event_date DESC) EVENTS
GROUP BY EVENTS.type,EVENTS.instruction_id;
```

Query 2:

```
select * 
from 
(SELECT * 
FROM EVENTS 
WHERE EVENTS.type='appointment'
ORDER BY EVENTS.event_date DESC) EVENTS
GROUP BY EVENTS.type;
```

Comment: Have you checked in sql fiddle that is wrong output

Comment: I just took your query to correct it if you need based on type only then remove instruction_id from group by then you will get based on grouped by type only...you can check 2nd query otherwise let me know what output you need..

Comment: if you are talking about my suggested 2 queries then first will group the result basd on 2 fields while 2nd will only based on type field and will provide different results...if you are talking about sub query then it is required because mysql ordering as mysql follow first where then group then having then order but here we required order by first and then group by, so we have to put first order by results in a sub query...

Answer (score 1):

If you want the latest of only "appointment type" grouping by event type:

```
SELECT max(EVENT.event_date) -- use other fields
FROM EVENTS 
WHERE EVENTS.type='appointment'
GROUP BY EVENTS.instruction_id;
```

Because if you filter by one specific type you will only get the max date of that type. If you want to get the max date of each type

```
SELECT max(EVENT.event_date) -- use other fields
FROM EVENTS 
GROUP BY EVENTS.type, EVENTS.instruction_id
```

EDIT: if you add the rest of the fields is working as you expected. Anyway, I paste you the query tested:

```
    SELECT ID, INSTRUCTION_ID, TYPE, COMMENT, max(EVENT_DATE) EVENT_DATE 
    FROM EVENTS 
    WHERE EVENTS.type='appointment'
    GROUP BY EVENTS.instruction_id
ORDER BY EVENT_DATE;
```

Comment: Have you checked in sql fiddle that is wrong output as per my expected output

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sorry for accept but i give upvote.

Comment: No worries, both solutions are right. You may check the performance in every case. Maybe this article could help you: http://explainextended.com/2010/01/30/aggregates-subqueries-vs-group-by/